# annotate Model Country field with country name

Tags: python, django

I want to filter a class (Region) and annotate it with Country name.

```
class SearchInput(TextInput):
input_type = "search"

class RegionUniversalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
query = django_filters.CharFilter(
method="universal_search",
label="",
widget=SearchInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Search..."}),
)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ['name','country']
    
    def universal_search(self, queryset, name, value):
        
       
        AllRegionCountry = AllRegion.annotate(countryname=Value(dict(countries)[F('country')], output_field=CharField()))
        
        
        return AllRegionCountry.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(country__icontains=value) | Q(countryname__icontains=value)
        )
```

And i have an error :

KeyError at /regions

F(country)

On the other hand :
`AllRegionCountry = AllRegion.annotate(countryname=Value(dict(countries)\["NZ"\], output_field=CharField()))`  WORK

So, how to evaluate `F('country')` ?

Regards

Comment: Please share the corresponding models... Why is `F('country')` a `CharField`?

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't* make `country` a simple `CharField`. An easy way to handle this is to work with a model that contains the ISO 3166-1-2 (or any other) code as unique primary key, and then the name:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    code2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, verbose_name='ISO 3166-1-2 code', primary_key=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

you can use the dictionary to feed the models with:

```
Country.objects.bulk_create(
    [Country(code2=k, name=v) for k, v in dict(countries).items()]
)
```

and then work with a `ForeignKey` that targets that model:

```
class AllRegion(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # …
```

that makes it easy to then filter with:

```
class RegionUniversalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    query = django_filters.CharFilter(
        method='universal_search',
        label='',
        widget=SearchInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search...'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ['name', 'country_id']

    def universal_search(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=value)
            | Q(country_id__icontains=value)
            | Q(country__name__icontains=value)
        )
```